# How can I multiply user input to create additional fields?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to multiply the value that is entered in the `userInput` field by 20 so that the fields with class `xafields` display 20 times what is entered in the `userInput`. (Enter 1, 20 of each field is added, enter 2, 40 of each field is added, etc.).

```js
jQuery("#userInput").change(function() {
  var htmlString = "";
  var len = jQuery(this).val();
  for (var i = 0; i <= len; i++) {

    htmlString += 'Name<br /><input class="xafields" type="text"><br />';
    htmlString += 'Email<br /><input class="xafields"><br /><br />';

  }
  jQuery("#xafieldContainer").html(htmlString);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="userInput">
<div id="xafieldContainer"></div>
```

Comment: before the loop, multiply you `len` by 20.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the changes and comments in the code:

Simply multiply the value entered by 20.

Make sure you start from one in the loop, not zero

```js
jQuery("#userInput").change(function() {
  var htmlString = "";
  var len = jQuery(this).val() * 20; /* Multiply value entered by 20 */
  for (var i = 1; i <= len; i++) { /* <-- start at 1, not 0 */

    htmlString += 'Name<br /><input class="xafields" type="text"><br />';
    htmlString += 'Email<br /><input class="xafields"><br /><br />';

  }
  jQuery("#xafieldContainer").html(htmlString);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="userInput">
<div id="xafieldContainer"></div>
```